# Sending GET requests to non-servers?

Tags: network, http

I ran a couple of wireshark runs for my computer and noticed inbound GET requests.

Is it legitimate traffic for there to be GET request traffic inbound to my home computer if my home computer isn't a server?

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but no update? I'm curious is this is happening on port 80, and if so I'd check to make sure you don't have any services running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues here.

First off, I am assuming you are talking about an HTTP GET request. These requests are sent once a connection is established, so you would need to have a port open to see this.

With that said, it doesn't matter what port you have open or what service is running on that  port. The GET might fail, but it is surely possible for someone to send it to any listening socket.

You mentioned that this is your home computer. Most home computers are behind a router using NAT. If this was the case, you would need to explicitly forward external ports to your internal IP in order for an outside connection to be established with your internal address.

So in short, yes its possible. It's also possible that this is a false positive or misinterpretation. If you want to know more, you need to provide more details.